# PHP move duplicates in recursive array

Tags: php, arrays

I building a translation form that is build using a array filled with the translation keys, to keys are however often duplicated. As the form is builded in group i want to move the duplicates to the `$translatables['global']`
Note that what you're seeing in the image below is already placed in `$translatables['modules']['Module_{{ModuleName}}']`

As you can see in the image below, some fields are duplicates. those needs to be moved. The duplicates can be placed accross multiple elements. 
[image: If the issue isn't clear you can see it here]

I edit for the duplicate message: It ain't, its a question to move those values not to filter them (and keep 1 remaining), they need to be placed under a global section.

Comment: @Anant it ain't a duplicate, its a request to move the element not to filter it. Please read it more carefully before placing such suggestion as it influence my score and the post feedback negatively.

Comment: @IMarks  it's said `possible duplicate` not `exact duplicate`. Still wait for some time, you will get something. Meanwhile i am not a down-voter.

Comment: @Anant is automaticly recognized by stackoverflow. I appriciate the removal, i don't care about the score as i already got ('far') above the privilege scores i require, it's more that people are less interest to react on minus scores posts. Also i appriciate the duplicate notice (if it give me the required answer), you trying to help me with it, so no hard feelings done ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself

```
class Tools_Array
{
    public static function find_duplicates_recursive(&$array, $remove = false)
    {
        $duplicates = array();

        $valueCounts = array_count_values(self::array_values_recursive($array));
        foreach ($valueCounts as $key => $value) {
            if ($value > 1)
            {
                $duplicates[] = $key;
            }
        }

        if ($remove) {
            foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
            {
                $array = self::remove_values_recursive($array, $duplicate);
            }
        }

        return $duplicates;
    }

    public static function array_values_recursive($array)
    {
        $arr2 = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                $arr2 = array_merge(array_values_recursive($value), $arr2);
            }else{
                $arr2[] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $arr2;
    }

    public static function remove_values_recursive($array, $needle)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                $array[$key] = self::remove_values_recursive($value, $needle);
            }else{
                if ($value == $needle)
                {
                    unset($array[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        return $array;
    }
}
```

Then i can filter it with:

```
$duplicates = Tools_Array::find_duplicates_recursive($translatables, true);
$translatables['globaal'] = array_merge($translatables['globaal'], $duplicates);
```